# How to assign subtotal from one function to another function?

Tags: python, flask, shelve, python-class

I have to set the `total_cost` variable to be equal to the subtotal variable or the from the product class. However, when I try to derive the value from the class. It gives me an attribute error of `AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute '_Product__total_price'`. I am implementing where you apply the promo code then it will deduct the total price from the cart.

This is `init.py` and functions used.

```
@app.route('/applyPromo/<string:id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def apply_promo(id):
    promotions_dict = {}
    db = shelve.open('promotions.db','w')
    promotions_dict = db['Promotions']
    total_cost = 100
    hidden = True
    applied = True
    click = True
    get_from_class = False
    print(promotions_dict)
    promotions = promotions_dict.get(UUID(id))
    db = shelve.open('storage.db', 'r')
    product_dict = db['products']
    for key in product_dict:
        product = product_dict[key]
        total_cost = product.get_total_price()
    print(total_cost)


    #when user apply promo, promo will get deleted from the list/dictionary of promos they have.
    if promotions["type"] == 1:
        total_cost = total_cost - 10
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    elif promotions["type"] == 2:
        total_cost = total_cost - 5
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    elif promotions["type"] == 3:
        total_cost = (70/100)*total_cost
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    elif promotions["type"] == 4:
        total_cost = (80/100)*total_cost
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    elif promotions["type"] == 5:
        total_cost = (85/100)*total_cost
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    else:
        total_cost = (90/100)*total_cost
        hidden = False
        print(f"Total Cost : {total_cost}")
        promotions_dict.pop(UUID(id))

    db['Promotions'] = promotions_dict
    db.close()
    db.close()
    print(promotions_dict)


    session['promotion_applied'] = promotions["id"]

    return render_template("generatePromo.html", total_cost=total_cost,applied=applied, promotions_dict=promotions_dict,hidden=hidden,promotions=promotions,get_from_class=get_from_class, click=click)

@app.route('/shopping_cart')
def shopping_cart():
    # session.clear()
    error = None
    cart_items = []
    quantity_list = []
    subtotal = 0
    db = shelve.open('storage.db', 'r')
    product_dict = db['products']
    db.close()

    for products in session:
        item = product_dict.get(products)
        cart_items.append(item)

        if None in cart_items:
            cart_items.remove(None)

        quantity_list.append(session[products])

        if products in quantity_list:
            quantity_list.remove(products)

    for i in range(len(cart_items)):
        cart_items[i].set_purchased_quantity(quantity_list[i])
        # set total price for single item
        item_total = int(cart_items[i].get_price()) * int(cart_items[i].get_purchased_quantity())
        cart_items[i].set_total_price(item_total)
        # set total price of all items in cart
        subtotal += item_total

    print('QTY LIST', quantity_list)
    print('CART', cart_items)

    if not cart_items:
        error = "Cart Is Empty"

    return render_template('shoppingcart.html', products_list=cart_items, error=error, subtotal=subtotal)
```

This is the product class.

```
from uuid import uuid4

class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, color, vase, remarks):
        self.__product__id = str(uuid4())
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price
        self.__quantity = quantity
        self.__color = color
        self.__vase = vase
        self.__remarks = remarks
        self.__purchased_quantity = 0
        self.__total_price = 0

    def get_product_id(self):
        return self.__product__id

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.__quantity

    def get_color(self):
        return self.__color

    def get_vase(self):
        return self.__vase

    def get_remarks(self):
        return self.__remarks

    def get_image(self):
        return self.__image

    def get_purchased_quantity(self):
        return self.__purchased_quantity

    def get_total_price(self):
        return self.__total_price

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def set_quantity(self, quantity):
        self.__quantity = quantity

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.__color = color

    def set_vase(self, vase):
        self.__vase = vase

    def set_remarks(self, remarks):
        self.__remarks = remarks

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.__image = image

    def set_purchased_quantity(self, purchased_quantity):
        self.__purchased_quantity = purchased_quantity

    def set_total_price(self, total_price):
        self.__total_price = total_price
```

This is the traceback for the error.

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B98PJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Leading double underscores should not be used as you are using them to define attributes of your class - single underscores is conventional.  The problem with using leading double underscores is that the interpreter "mangles" the names of those attributes to avoid a subtle problem with inheritance, but leading to the problem, I believe, you are seeing.  Here is a [good read on the subject](https://medium.com/python-features/naming-conventions-with-underscores-in-python-791251ac7097).

Comment: i changed the self.__total_price to self._total_price but the same problem still occurs. What should i do?

Comment: Uh oh, that is bad news for my theory. ;^)  Can you include the traceback output you get when the error occurs, so we can see the lines of code that are giving rise to the error?

Comment: i have included the traceback output in the post. Please do take a look at it :)

Comment: The traceback still shows code with leading double underscores: `self.__total_price` Is this after you made the change?

Comment: at first i changed the underscores from double to single but it still came out the same problem so i redo to double underscores

Comment: for some reason, why i copy my `checkout` function codes to my `apply_promo` function codes, then i can set my `total_cost` variable = `subtotal` variable. But, is there any other way for me to derive the `subtotal` from checkout function without copy paste the codes exactly?